# Aerospike - command execution timed out on client

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

Using the following code to load data in Aerospike. data is a list of maps of type BinMap

```
for _, binMap := range data {
   id, ok := binMap["id"].(string)
   key, _ := as.NewKey("test", "myset", id)
   err := shared.Client.Put(nil, key, binMap) 
   if err !=nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
 }
```

After loading few records, the following error message is received.

```
command execution timed out on client: Exceeded number of retries. 
See `Policy.MaxRetries`. (last error: Node not found for partition 
test:711 in partition table.)
```

For each iteration, the partition test number changes.
The error continues even after waiting for 5 seconds after each Put command. I am not sure what timeout is reported in the error message.What client configuration is required for go client?

Using MacOs 10.15.3; go client; Aerospike running on docker 2.2.0.3

Comment: Your client is not successfully connecting to all the "nodes" of the Aerospike cluster - each node sends its partition ownership to the client. There are 4K partitions. Each record belongs to a unique partition id. So client keeps trying to write to the node that is the owner of partition 711 above and gives up after retrying.

Comment: I am running single node cluster.  Just followed the directions here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/vagrant/mac/index.html. Is multi-node installation required?

Comment: no, don't need multi-node cluster. single node cluster is fine. so you are losing connectivity to the node from the client. this is again probably docker related.

Comment: It appears that the go client is messed up. I cannot perform any read/write operation. If I restart the application (go client), I can perform read/write. It is the performing the  write operation in a loop that messes up the go client.

Comment: 'Messed up' is kind of a generalization. Quite a few heavily used applications interfacing with Aerospike are written in Go, including services for Snapchat. So the Go client definitely works. Open a bug in the repo, if you can reproduce the problem: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good chance your cluster hasn't formed correctly, or that its networking isn't properly set up to give clients access to all the nodes. Since you're using Docker, take a look at Lucien's Medium post [How do I get a 2 nodes Aerospike cluster running quickly in Docker without editing a single file?](https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/how-do-i-get-a-2-node-aerospike-cluster-running-quickly-in-docker-without-editing-a-single-file-1c2a94564a99).

Comment: he is testing with a single node.

Comment: Seems like the client can't talk to the server, meaning a networking issue.

Comment: While storing records in a loop, after few iterations, communication fails. First four or five records are stored in database without problem.

Comment: Please open an issue https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go . People use this client in production quite intensively, so something is up but no idea what. Add a code sample, output and not your server version, client version, OS at client and server. It’s a mystery

Comment: Time format in my data might be causing some issues. Still investigating.